# Google activity. Is this how a video call shows?

Tags: samsung, google

What does it mean when all 3 of these show together in Google activity?

- com.sec.Android.app.camera
- com.Samsung.Android.incallui
- com.Samsung.Android.dialer

This is on an s22 ultra. I think the video calls on default for the phone would show as Google Meet? I'm not sure.